# What is the reason for observing a wiper voltage greater than the A and B PIN of a digital potentiometer?

Tags: digital-potentiometer, current-sink

I am working on a project to implement a variable resistance for high voltage circuit using a MOSFET current sink. [The complete circuit is available here.](https://oshwlab.com/sigrama/2022-09-06-fault-emulator-for-old-pdc)

I am sharing the first page of the circuit here:

[image: Page 1 of the schematics]

One part of the circuit uses a digital potentiometer, where I have a problem. When I connect 24VDC at the BE and PHASE pins, I measured 41.3mV at POT-MAX with respect to GND-HVDC.

I am expecting voltage between 0 to 41.3mV at POT-PW3, but I measure 81mV. Please help me understand how the voltage at the wiper can be greater than the voltage at pins A and B.

Comment: At what point are you measuring said voltage?

Comment: @VoltageSpike , I measured 81mV at POT-PW3

Comment: Grounding point

Comment: @VoltageSpike, I am measuring it w.r.t. GND-HVDC

Answer (score 2):

The OP-07 is a (very old) bipolar precision amplifier with superbeta transistors at the inputs. They are protected by two series back-to-back pairs of diodes and series resistors. So if there is a significant differential voltage (in relation to a diode drop) then current can flow from one input to the other. These elements are not shown on the TI simplified internal schematic.

So if your op-amp's inverting input is at some voltage other than ~0V relative to the other input you can see current flowing in or out of the non-inverting input.

If that does not seem to be the problem, remove the op-amp entirely (or interrupt the connection to the non-inverting input of U5) and measure again at the digital potentiometer wiper.

Comment: I will remove the chip and measure it again. I will update here the results.

Comment: Incase OP-07 is the culprit, what are the other alternative? Do you have any suggestions? Do you think LM358 is a good option?

Comment: The LM358 won't behave that way. However it's not as accurate as the OP-07 in terms of Vos, TCVos, gain etc.  A 2mV error represents about 0.6mA error in your current sink. Typically it will be more like 50 or 100uA error. Up to you whether that's an important amount of error. The popular OP177 is a much more precise choice but it's not 100% clear to me that it will be completely free of this issue from the datasheet. It should, at a minimum, be much better.

Comment: The Analog Device datasheet for OP-07 is [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/op07.pdf), and for OP-117 is [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/op177.pdf). Both of them show some diodes between input terminals. Means, they may show same problem, right? I am not allowed to enter the lab until 3rd Jan, so I cannot report the experiment results until then.

Comment: @SKGadi I think they will behave identically, TI just simplified their schematic a bit more. But I've never tested to be sure. Note that this should not be an issue if the circuit is actually balanced.

Comment: May be by removing the 1Mega ohm resistor R132 would solve the problem. Any comments?

Comment: Now the results are strange. The POT-MAX gives voltage 2.2V. I removed R132, then U3 and U5. Still the POT-MAX is measuring 2.2V. I think the U9 digital POT is damaged now. I don't have a spare component to replace.

Answer (score 0):

> Please help me understand how the voltage at the wiper can be greater than the voltage at pins A and B.

Something else is pushing current into the potentiometer. Remember: functionally, it's a resistive divider. You can force the middle node of a resistive divider to any potential - it just depends on how hard you drive it :) E.g. a 10k/10k divider between 0V and 5V can have the middle node driven to 20V if you put a 20V source on it, no problem. You're doing something like that with the digital potentiometer.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but unsure which element is pushing current into it. The wiper is connected to positive input of the OP-AMP.